# Why is this faster and is it safe to use? (WHERE first letter is in the alphabet)

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2017

Long story short, we're updating small tables of people with values from a very large table of people. In a recent test, this update takes ca 5 minutes to run.

We stumbled upon what seems like the silliest optimization possible, that seemingly works perfectly! The same query now runs in less than 2 minutes and produces the same results, perfectly.

Here is the query. The last line is added as "the optimization". Why the intense decrease in query time? Are we missing something? Could this lead to problems in the future?

```
UPDATE smallTbl
SET smallTbl.importantValue = largeTbl.importantValue
FROM smallTableOfPeople smallTbl
JOIN largeTableOfPeople largeTbl
    ON largeTbl.birth_date = smallTbl.birthDate
    AND DIFFERENCE(TRIM(smallTbl.last_name),TRIM(largeTbl.last_name)) = 4
    AND DIFFERENCE(TRIM(smallTbl.first_name),TRIM(largeTbl.first_name)) = 4
WHERE smallTbl.importantValue IS NULL
-- The following line is "the optimization"
AND LEFT(TRIM(largeTbl.last_name), 1) IN ('a','à','á','b','c','d','e','è','é','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','ô','ö','p','q','r','s','t','u','ü','v','w','x','y','z','æ','ä','ø','å')
```

*Technical notes: We are aware that the list of letters to test might need a few more letters. We are also aware of the obvious margin for error when using "DIFFERENCE".*

**Query plan (regular):** https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rypV84y7V 
**Query plan (with "optimization"):** https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1aC2my7E

Comment: Small reply to your technical note: `AND LEFT(TRIM(largeTbl.last_name), 1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI` should do what you want there without requiring you to list all characters and having code that's difficult to read

Comment: Do you have rows where the final condition in the `WHERE` is false? In particular note that the comparison might be case sensitive.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth makes an excellent point. But, just a small technical note: for SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2, it's best to use the version "100" collations (if available for the culture / locale being used). So that would be `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`. And for SQL Server 2012 and newer (through at least SQL Server 2019), it's best to use the Supplementary Character-enabled collations in the highest version for the locale being used. So that would be `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC` in this case. Versions > 100 (only Japanese so far) don't have (or need) `_SC` (e.g. `Japanese_XJIS_140_CI_AI`).

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the data in your tables, your indexes, .... Hard to say without being able to compare the execution plans / the io + time statistics.

The difference I would expect is the extra filtering happening before the JOIN between the two tables.
In my example, I changed the updates to selects to reuse my tables.

**The execution plan with "the optimization"**
[image]

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyMsaQym4)

*You clearly see a filter operation happening, in my test data no records where filtered out and as a result no improvements where made.*

**The execution plan, without "the optimization"**
[image]

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkswpXk7V)

*The filter is gone, which means that we will have to rely on the join to filter out unneeded records.*

**Other reason(s)**
Another reason / consequence of changing the query could be, that a new execution plan was created when changing the query, which happens to be faster.
An example of this is the engine choosing a different Join operator, but that is just guessing at this point.

**EDIT:**

Clarifying after getting the two query plans:

The query is reading 550M Rows from the big table, and filtering them out.
[image]

Meaning that the predicate is the one doing most of the filtering, not the seek predicate. Resulting in the data being read, but way less being returned.

Making sql server use a different index  (query plan) / adding an index could resolve this.

**So why doesn't the optimize query have this same issue?**

Because a different query plan is used, with a scan instead of a seek.

[image]
[image]

Without doing any seeks, but only returning 4M rows to work with.

**Next difference**

Disregarding the update difference ( nothing is being updated on the optimized query)
a hash match is used on the optimized query:

[image]

Instead of a nested loop join on the non-optimized:

[image]

A nested loop is best when one table is small and the other one big. Since they are both close to the same size I would argue that the hash match is the better choice in this case.

**Overview**

*The optimized query* 
[image]

The Optimized query's plan has parallellism, uses a hash match join, and needs to do less residual IO filtering. It also uses a bitmap to eliminate key values that cannot produce any join rows . (Also nothing is being updated)

*The non-optimized query* 
[image]
The non-Optimized query's plan has no parallellism, uses a nested loop join, and needs to do residual IO filtering on 550M records. (Also the update is happening)

**What could you do to improve the non-optimized query?**

- Changing the index to have first_name & last_name in the key column
  list:

  CREATE INDEX IX_largeTableOfPeople_birth_date_first_name_last_name
  on dbo.largeTableOfPeople(birth_date,first_name,last_name)
  include(id)

But due to the use of functions and this table being big this might not be the optimal solution.

- Updating statistics, using recompile to try and get the better plan.
- Adding OPTION`(HASH JOIN, MERGE JOIN)` to the query
- ...

---

**Test data + Queries used**

```
CREATE TABLE #smallTableOfPeople(importantValue int, birthDate datetime2, first_name varchar(50),last_name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE #largeTableOfPeople(importantValue int, birth_date datetime2, first_name varchar(50),last_name varchar(50));


set nocount on;
DECLARE @i int = 1
WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN
insert into #smallTableOfPeople (importantValue,birthDate,first_name,last_name)
VALUES(NULL, dateadd(mi,@i,'2018-01-18 11:05:29.067'),'Frodo','Baggins');

set @i += 1;
END


set nocount on;
DECLARE @j int = 1
WHILE @j <= 20000
BEGIN
insert into #largeTableOfPeople (importantValue,birth_Date,first_name,last_name)
VALUES(@j, dateadd(mi,@j,'2018-01-18 11:05:29.067'),'Frodo','Baggins');

set @j += 1;
END


SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;

SELECT  smallTbl.importantValue , largeTbl.importantValue
FROM #smallTableOfPeople smallTbl
JOIN #largeTableOfPeople largeTbl
    ON largeTbl.birth_date = smallTbl.birthDate
    AND DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(smallTbl.last_name)),RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.last_name))) = 4
    AND DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(smallTbl.first_name)),RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.first_name))) = 4
WHERE smallTbl.importantValue IS NULL
-- The following line is "the optimization"
AND LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.last_name)), 1) IN ('a','à','á','b','c','d','e','è','é','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','ô','ö','p','q','r','s','t','u','ü','v','w','x','y','z','æ','ä','ø','å');

SELECT  smallTbl.importantValue , largeTbl.importantValue
FROM #smallTableOfPeople smallTbl
JOIN #largeTableOfPeople largeTbl
    ON largeTbl.birth_date = smallTbl.birthDate
    AND DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(smallTbl.last_name)),RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.last_name))) = 4
    AND DIFFERENCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(smallTbl.first_name)),RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.first_name))) = 4
WHERE smallTbl.importantValue IS NULL
-- The following line is "the optimization"
--AND LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(largeTbl.last_name)), 1) IN ('a','à','á','b','c','d','e','è','é','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','ô','ö','p','q','r','s','t','u','ü','v','w','x','y','z','æ','ä','ø','å')




drop table #largeTableOfPeople;
drop table #smallTableOfPeople;
```

Answer (score 8):

It is not clear that the second query is in fact an improvement.

The execution plans contain QueryTimeStats that show a much less dramatic difference than stated in the question.

The slow plan had an elapsed time of `257,556 ms` (4 mins 17 seconds). The fast plan had an elapsed time of `190,992 ms` (3 mins 11 seconds) despite running with a degree of parallelism of 3.

Moreover the second plan was running in a database where there was no work to do after the join.

### First Plan

[image]

### Second Plan

[image]

So that extra time could well be explained by the work needed to update 3.5 million rows (the work required in the update operator to locate these rows, latch the page, write the update to the page and transaction log is not negligible)

*If* this is in fact reproducible when comparing like with like then the explanation is that you just got lucky in this case.

The filter with the 37 `IN` conditions only eliminated 51 rows out of the 4,008,334 in the table but the optimiser considered it would eliminate much more

[image]

```
   LEFT(TRIM(largeTbl.last_name), 1) IN ( 'a', 'à', 'á', 'b',
                                          'c', 'd', 'e', 'è',
                                          'é', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                                          'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                                          'm', 'n', 'o', 'ô',
                                          'ö', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                                          's', 't', 'u', 'ü',
                                          'v', 'w', 'x', 'y',
                                          'z', 'æ', 'ä', 'ø', 'å' )
```

Such incorrect cardinality estimations are usually a bad thing. In this case it  produced a differently shaped (and parallel) plan which apparently (?) worked better for you despite the hash spills caused by the massive underestimate.

Without the `TRIM` SQL Server is able to convert this to a range interval in the base column histogram and give much more accurate estimates but with the `TRIM` it just resorts to guesses.

The nature of the guess can vary but the estimate for a single predicate on `LEFT(TRIM(largeTbl.last_name), 1)` is in some circumstances <sup>*</sup> just estimated to be `table_cardinality/estimated_number_of_distinct_column_values`.

<sub>I'm not sure exactly what circumstances - size of data seems to play a part. I was able to reproduce this with wide fixed length datatypes [as here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=870f313f47031dd060de0df33a6af1c0) but got a different, higher, guess with `varchar` (which just used a flat 10% guess and estimated 100,000 rows). [@Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky) points out that if the `varchar(100)` is padded with trailing spaces as happens for `char` the lower estimate is used</sub>

The `IN` list is expanded out to `OR` and SQL Server uses [exponential backoff](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2014/04/cardinality-estimation-for-disjunctive-predicates-in-2014.html) with a maximum of 4 predicates considered. So the `219.707` estimate is arrived at as follows.

```
DECLARE @TableCardinality FLOAT = 4008334, 
        @DistinctColumnValueEstimate FLOAT = 34207

DECLARE @NotSelectivity float = 1 - (1/@DistinctColumnValueEstimate)

SELECT @TableCardinality * ( 1 - (
@NotSelectivity * 
SQRT(@NotSelectivity) * 
SQRT(SQRT(@NotSelectivity)) * 
SQRT(SQRT(SQRT(@NotSelectivity)))
))
```